How to increase speed Lottie animation speed in react?
I want to increase the speed of Lottie animation in react but it didn't work. This is my code
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';
import animationData from './Lottie_meregala.json';

const ConfettiAnimation = () => {
  const speed = 2;

  // Optimized defaultOptions using useMemo to avoid unnecessary updates
  const defaultOptions = useMemo(() => ({
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animationData,
    rendererSettings: {
      preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice'
    }
  }), []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'flex-end', height: '100vh' }}>
      <Lottie options={defaultOptions} height={400} width={400} speed={speed} />
00     </div>
  );
};

export default ConfettiAnimation;

I want to increase the speed of this confetti animation but it didn't work me please help me

This speed related code is AI generated. Other code is i found on the lottie animation. This is the link: https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie-animations/how-to-use-lottie-in-react-app
